# Why would this tell command start a program?

Tags: applescript

The following applescript is run as part of a larger program that I regularly use:

```
on run {viewer, path_to_pdf}
    if viewer is "Skim" then
        display notification "Skim opened: " & viewer & "!!!"
        tell application "Skim"
            revert (documents whose path is path_to_pdf as text)
        end tell
    else if viewer is "TeXShop" then
        display notification "TexShop opened: " & viewer & "!!!"
        tell application "TeXShop"
            tell documents whose path is path_to_pdf as text to refreshpdf
        end tell
    end if
end run
```

I currently have the viewer set to skim in this larger program so when this script runs I get the notification "Skim opened: Skim!!!" and skim refreshes my pdf as one would expect.  **But TeXShop also opens!**

I believe this is the code that causes TeXShop to open because if I delete `tell application "TeXShop" ... end tell` from the code then skim refreshes as expected and TeXShop **doesn't** open.  I'm confused because I never get the display notification that TeXShop is opening.  This script is only called once per run and per the notification it's being passed "Skim" as an argument, so that block of code is not being executed... except it still has effects on the system??

Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: You have a syntax error.... Your else if is contained within the if statement so it's being treated as an else statement to a always false if statement

Comment: If that's true then shouldn't the "TeXShop opened" notification be displayed?  Also what should the correct syntax be?  This syntax looks the same as what I see in the "if (compound)" section of the language guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html)

Comment: Did you compile the script or not? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/12431811/3449216

Comment: It is not compiled.  I think that link (which I was unaware of) explains everything, thank you!